# Ing form as infinitive at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: verbs, infinitives, ing

Is it possible to use the ing form as infinitive at the beginning of a sentence?

E.g. learning extracurricular Software to improve personal training.

This is a sentence I put in brackets in my curriculum vitae.
If possible, attach references of accreditate sources where you picked up the rule.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This particular use of the _-ing_ form is called a "Gerund", and it does function in much the same way as an infinitive does. Infinitive clauses and gerund clauses are varieties of Complement clauses -- subordinate clauses that act as nouns in a sentence, typically the subject or direct object of certain verbs. The example you give -- _learning extracurricular software to improve personal training_ -- is not a sentence, however. It could be a sentence if it had a main verb, but as it is, it is only a gerund clause followed by a purpose infinitive clause.

Comment: That's fine, except it's not a complete standalone sentence. You need to add *is [something]* to the end. However, in the context of something broader that introduces it, as you indicate, that's okay. *Software* should not be capitalized—unless it's a proper noun, which seems unlikely.

Comment: John Lawler and Jason Bassford thank you for your precious suggestions.

Comment: Hello @JohnLawler, in my context it is better to use the gerund or the infinitive? The complete point in my CV is: Determination to achieve the prefixed goals (e.g. learning extracurricular softwares to improve my professional training).

Comment: If this text is for your CV, you have much bigger problems than gerund vs infinitive. To start with, _prefixed goals_ does not mean what you think it means, because it doesn't mean anything. And _software_ is a mass noun that doesn't occur in the plural. On the other hand, that might be normal in whatever dialect of English is spoken where you live; there are thousands.

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler, thus maybe in this way should be ok: Determination to achieve the set goals (e.g. learning extracurricular software to improve my professional training).

Comment: Better. Leave out _my_; if you're using anarthrous nouns elsewhere, continue.

Comment: @JohnLawler your help was very precious. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have the last question for you, related to your answers: can you suggest to me a book or a website where I can find a glossary of the linguistic terms please? I found the term anarthrous only in the dictionaries, but not in the glossaries.

Comment: _Anarthrous_ is a technical term, meaning (in Greek) 'without articles'. Try the glossaries in David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language_ or _Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_.

Comment: @JohnLawle I checked, but there is not.

Comment: There is not what?

Comment: Hello @JohnLawler, in the book you suggested to me there is not the word anarthrous.

Comment: So [look it up on google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=anarthrous) and find out how people use it. Only linguists (and possibly entomologists, in a different sense) would be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> This particular use of the *-ing* form is called a "Gerund", and it does function in much the same way as an infinitive does. Infinitive clauses and gerund clauses are varieties of Complement clauses -- subordinate clauses that act as nouns in a sentence, typically the subject or direct object of certain verbs. The example you give -- *learning extracurricular software to improve personal training* -- is not a sentence, however. It could be a sentence if it had a main verb, but as it is, it is only a gerund clause followed by a purpose infinitive clause.

And:

> If this text is for your CV, you have much bigger problems than gerund vs infinitive. To start with, *prefixed goals* does not mean what you think it means, because it doesn't mean anything. And *software* is a mass noun that doesn't occur in the plural. On the other hand, that might be normal in whatever dialect of English is spoken where you live; there are thousands.