# My job is to do something or doing something?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

- My job is to teach English.
- My job is teaching English.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [started-verb vs verb {started to teach vs started teaching}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64274/started-verb-vs-verb/64277#64277), and related [Catenatives followed by infinitives and gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25075/catenatives-followed-by-infinitives-and-gerunds).

Comment: Partly addressed at [ing-form / infinitive at the beginning of a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505336/ing-form-as-infinitive-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence/505493#505493) (J Lawler addresses where non-finite complement clauses can be used in a sentence). 'Teaching' here is the unmarked option; 'to teach' would either be used with a specification (as in Kate's answer) or as an emphatic response say, when a fellow teacher says you should often mention Elbonian communication methods to be multicultural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If teaching is your occupation, I would consider the gerund (teaching) to be more idiomatic. I would use  the infinitive when referring to a one-off task.

> My job was to teach the King of Ruritania's son to speak English.